# How can I change an emoji to 'face' the other way?

Tags: r, emoji

I am relatively new to R, so thank you for the help.
I would like to insert a running man emoji onto a graph, using the emo package.
This is the emoji I would like to use, but would like the running man to 'run' in the opposite direction, so he faces the right not the left.

emo::ji("man_running")
‍♂️

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure it is possible because the [github emojis](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908) as well as [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/man-running/) are only in one direction

Comment: @linog Thanks. Ended up using a png and flipping that!

Answer (score -2):

Copy(jpeg)the emoji in its original format. Editing through Word, Adobe, even your device's native picture editing software would typically work to reverse the emoji. Insert the finished product into your graph.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "No" would've been a far more useful reply.